# JSON serialization helper class

Tags: c#, object-oriented, .net, json, serialization

I wrote this class to one-line all my JSON serialization, and I'm curious of any input on it.

It's only responsible for serializing/deserializing any type to/from JSON.

The comments and code are pretty self explanatory, but if you want any extra explanation of it please feel free to comment.

Not a lot here, so comment on what you can.

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides methods for Serialization and Deserialization of JSON/JavaScript Object Notation documents.
/// </summary>
public class JsonSerialization
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Serializes an object to a JSON/JavaScript Object Notation string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the object to serialize.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="value">The object to serialize.</param>
    /// <param name="serializedJson">Filled with a string that is the JsonSerialized object.</param>
    /// <param name="throwErrors">If true, will throw errors. Otherwise, returns false on failures.</param>
    /// <returns>A boolean value indicating success.</returns>
    public static bool Serialize<T>(T value, ref string serializedJson, bool throwErrors = false)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

#if DEBUG
#warning When in DEBUG Mode JavaScript Serialization Errors will be thrown regardless of throwErrors parameter.
            throwErrors = true;
#endif

        try
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            serializedJson = jss.Serialize(value);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            if (throwErrors)
                throw;

            return false;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deserializes a JSON/JavaScript Object Notation string to an object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the object to serialize.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="value">The JSON string representing the serialized object.</param>
    /// <param name="deserializedObject">Filled with the object that is the JsonSerialized string.</param>
    /// <param name="throwErrors">If true, will throw errors. Otherwise, returns false on failures.</param>
    /// <returns>A boolean value indicating success.</returns>
    public static bool Deserialize<T>(string value, ref T deserializedObject, bool throwErrors = false)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

#if DEBUG
#warning When in DEBUG Mode JavaScript Deserialization Errors will be thrown regardless of throwErrors parameter.
            throwErrors = true;
#endif

        try
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            deserializedObject = jss.Deserialize<T>(value);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            if (throwErrors)
                throw;

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Style**

- The overall reading of these methods is pretty good and the code is well structured.
- The documentation is good to read and to understand.
- Your style is a little bit inconsistent. It's about the using of braces `{}` for single statement `if`'s . One time at the guard clause you use braces and later on for the `if(throwErrors)`  you don't use them.

  Speaking about `throwErrors`, the method won't ever throw errors but **one** `Exception` so a better name could be either `shouldThrowException` or `throwsException`.

---

Speaking about `Serialize()` method

I don't like `ref` parameters that much and I try to avoid them if there is a better/different way to solve this.

For the `Serialize()` method the usage of an `ref` parameter could be avoided by passing a `StringBuilder` instead of a `string` as argument.

You for sure would need to check if the passed in `StringBuilder` is not `null` but you could just pass it afterwards to [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb340417%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the `Serialize()` method.